# why doesn't my sorted code work in c?

Tags: c, list, insert, sorting

Here is my code. it doesn't work:

```
void insertioon (int d)   // this part, insert and sort list
{                     
    struct node *np, *temp, *prev;
    int found;

    np=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    np->data = d;
    np->nextPtr = NULL;

    temp=firstPtr;
    found=0;
    while ((temp != NULL) && !found)
    {

        if (temp->data <d)
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->nextPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            found=1;
        }

        if (prev == NULL)
        {
            np->nextPtr=firstPtr;
            firstPtr=np;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->nextPtr = np;
            np->nextPtr = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

What is my mistake ? in insertioon , I want to sort this list.

Comment: the insertion operation in the while-loop. and `prev` uninitialize.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY   but i write prev = temp;  and i initialize prev

Comment: You must be initialized to NULL before entering the loop.

Comment: Yes, but you also test whether `prev == NULL`. For this to work, you must initialise `prev` to `NULL`.

Comment: OK, I write prev=NULL , before the loop. So, in my code there is a different mistake ?? I don't see mistakes but it doesn't work completely. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: operation of insertion move to outside of while-loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY   I cancel opeation of insertion in while loop and I move it outside. But my code doen't sort :/

Comment: ?? it work fine to me. my test code up to answer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  now it works but i don't print for random numbers . I get the numbers :   srand(time(NULL)); 
int i,x;
for(i=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
 x=rand()%40;
 insertSorted(x);
 list=firstPtr;
    firstPtr=NULL; printList(firstPtr);
}      but it doesn't print these numbers

Comment: `firstPtr=NULL; printList(firstPtr);`, you set to NULL.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  ok , i understand your advice. I can ask a question to you.  i want to create a different list( but it has randomly numbers ), what will i do ? I tried somethings but when i set to NULL of firstPtr, it doen't work good for list2 . Please give me an advice :)

Comment: rewrite that does not use a global variable.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I rewrite code but there is a mistake. :/

Comment: try again. i think that `firstPtr` replace to argument of function and return of function.

Comment: E.g `list1=insertSorted(list1, x);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY OK, I change my insertSorted method with return node . And now it works fine :D Thank you so so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *nextPtr;
};

struct node *firstPtr = NULL;

void insertioon (int d){
    struct node *np, *temp, *prev = NULL;
    int found;

    np=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    np->data = d;
    np->nextPtr = NULL;

    temp=firstPtr;
    found=0;
    while ((temp != NULL) && !found)
    {

        if (temp->data <d)
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->nextPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            found=1;
        }
    }
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        np->nextPtr=firstPtr;
        firstPtr=np;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->nextPtr = np;
        np->nextPtr = temp;
    }
}

void print_list(struct node *np){
    while(np){
        printf("%d ", np->data);
        np=np->nextPtr;
    }
}

int main(){
    insertioon(10);
    insertioon(5);
    insertioon(7);
    insertioon(1);
    insertioon(16);
    print_list(firstPtr);//1 5 7 10 16
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/ULYI3C

Comment: Thank you so much , now it works.  I try work with random 10 numbers . I hope I can do it :)